# How to repeat tasks using semaphore in Task-Based Async Pattern n C#

Tags: c#

Need to print Task Id 100 times of 10 tasks/threads such that every task take a turn to print the id and then after 10th again the Tasks repeat to take turn. (Eg: On position 1, 11, 21,31,...91 => Task#1 should print its id)

I have created a semaphoreslim object with initialcount 1.
Then
I have created 10 Tasks and initialized with an Async method and started them.
In the method, Before the Task.Run code, i have awaited on Semaphore (await semaphoreslimobj.waitasync()) and then performed printing code and after that released semaphore.

It works for 10 tasks only once.. mean 10 Time the code runs and each task print its Id and exit.How to repeat same tasks?

Comment: please post the code and not only a description of it.

Comment: Is this an assignment? And is the goal specifically to use semaphores? Since the task of processing items in a batch in parallel, but each batch of items serially, would probably be easiest to do with a Parallel.For inside a regular for-loop.

Comment: Yes sort of an assignment. not necessarily to use semaphore but if anyone can guide or hint what to use with Async/await to carry this.